# SBT publish ignoring SSH key

Tags: sbt, ivy

### Updated Post

I'm trying to publish a library to a locally-hosted repository.  I've successfully done this before, but now running into trouble.

SBT should use an SSH key to log into the machine hosting the repository.  Instead, it's asking for a password.

Here's the `publishTo` setting with redacted values in CAPS:

```
publishTo := Some(
        Resolver
            .ssh("Degree Audit", "REPO_HOST_MACHINE", "/u1/HOST_ACCOUNT/public_html/maven")
            .as("HOST_ACCOUNT", file(sys.env("HOME") + "/.ssh/oat_rsa"), None)
            .withPublishPermissions("0644")
    ),
```

The password prompt is a dialog box with the Ivy logo on it.

Changing the name of the SSH key to a non-existent file does not make a difference.  But SBT is clearly reading the key because `show publishTo` yields (again, some redacting):

```
[info] Some(SshRepository(Degree Audit, 
  Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(),artifactPatterns=Vector(/u1/HOST_ACCOUNT/public_html/maven/[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]), 
  isMavenCompatible=true, 
  descriptorOptional=false, 
  skipConsistencyCheck=false), 
  SshConnection(
    Some(KeyFileAuthentication(HOST_ACCOUNT, /PATH/TO/.ssh/oat_rsa, None)), 
    Some(REPO_HOST_MACHINE), 
    None), 
  Some(0644)))
```

Yes, `ssh HOST_ACCOUNT@REPO_HOST_MACHINE -i .ssh/oat_rsa` connects just fine.

If I cancel the password dialog box SBT throws a `NullPointerException`.  If I provide a bogus value, I get a stack trace via `last publish` that starts like this:

```
sbt:oat-degreeAudit> last publish
[debug] :: SSH :: connecting to REPO_HOST_MACHINE...
[error] java.io.IOException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many authentication failures 
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.ssh.SshCache.getSession(SshCache.java:338)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.ssh.AbstractSshBasedRepository.getSession(AbstractSshBasedRepository.java:108)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.ssh.SshRepository.put(SshRepository.java:238)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.AbstractRepository.put(AbstractRepository.java:130)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.put(RepositoryResolver.java:234)
[error]     at org.apache.ivy.plugins.resolver.RepositoryResolver.publish(RepositoryResolver.java:216)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$publish$5(IvyActions.scala:504)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyUtil$.retryWithBackoff(IvyUtil.scala:22)
```

#### Questions

- Should changing `.ssh/oat_rsa` to `.ssh/oat_rsaXXX` (a non-existent filename) throw an error?
- Is there a way to trace the SSH calls between SBT and the server?  Or at least verify that SBT is actually trying to use my SSH key?
- If SBT can't connect via SSH, does it automatically fall back to a password?
- The [SBT documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html#Credentials) says "NOTE: Credentials matching is done using both: realm and host keys. The realm key is the HTTP WWW-Authenticate header’s realm directive, which is part of the response of HTTP servers for HTTP Basic Authentication."  Is that relevant to my situation?  If so, can someone unpack that for me?
- Finally, any other light to shed on this problem or how to debug it?

### Previous Post; Ignore

I tried to publish a new Scala library today using SBT v1.8.3.  I modelled the build file on another library I've published a month or two ago in the same way.

To my surprise, publishing asked for a password instead of using my SSH key.

I tried the same tasks with the previously working library.  It did the same (unlike the last time I published it), so obviously something changed in my environment/setup -- but what?

Here's the `build.sbt` for the library that previously "worked" (published to a local maven repo using ssh keys).  Slightly redacted.

```
import sbt.Keys.publishLocalConfiguration
import sbtcrossproject.CrossPlugin.autoImport.{CrossType, crossProject}

val sharedSettings = Seq(
  version      := "2.0.11-SNAPSHOT",
  name         := "...",
  organization := "...",
  scalaVersion := "3.2.2",
  crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.13.10", scalaVersion.value ),
  versionScheme := Some("semver-spec"),
  scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-language:reflectiveCalls"),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...),
  publishConfiguration      := publishConfiguration.value.withOverwrite(true),
  publishLocalConfiguration := publishLocalConfiguration.value.withOverwrite(true)
)

lazy val oatlibxp = crossProject(JSPlatform, JVMPlatform)
  .crossType(CrossType.Pure)
  .settings(sharedSettings)

val keyFile: File = file(sys.env("HOME") + "/.ssh/oat_rsa")

val publishMavenStyle = true

ThisBuild / publishTo := Some(
  Resolver
    .ssh("OAT Lib Cross-platform", "example.ca", "/u1/username/public_html/maven")
    .as("username", keyFile)
    .withPublishPermissions("0644")
)
```

It's a Java process that asks for the passwords.  If I cancel, SBT says it can't publish for lack of credentials.  When I quit that password-asking-process, SBT itself quits.

Any ideas how to debug this?  Again, I don't think it's the build file because the above used to work but now shows the same misbehaviour as the new one.

### Update

- I've blown away ~/.sbtopts and sbt.  Reinstalled.  No change.
- I blew away the Ivy cache and the Coursier cache.  Upon compiling, all the dependencies were downloaded to the Coursier cache.  `publish` asked for a password using an Ivy-branded dialog box instead of using SSH keys.
- `show useCoursier` yields `true`.
- `show publishTo` yields (some newlines added manually; MACHINE_NAME, USERID, MY-USERID redacted):

```
Some(SshRepository(
  OAT Lib Cross-platform, 
  Patterns(ivyPatterns=Vector(), 
artifactPatterns=Vector(public_html/maven/[organisation]/[module](_[scalaVersion])(_[sbtVersion])/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]), 
  isMavenCompatible=true, 
  descriptorOptional=false,
  skipConsistencyCheck=false),
  SshConnection(
    Some(KeyFileAuthentication(USERID,
      /Users/MY-USERID/.ssh/oat_rsa, None)),
    Some(MACHINE_NAME), None), Some(0644)))
```

So, why does SBT ask for my password rather than use my SSH key?

Answer (score 0):

--Check `SSH key` permissions: `SSH` key file (`oat_rsa` in this case) should have the correct permissions set. The file should be readable by the user running SBT, but not readable by others.

```
chmod 600 /PATH/TO/.ssh/oat_rsa
```

--Confirm SSH key passphrase: If your `SSH` key is encrypted with a passphrase, SBT will prompt for the passphrase when it tries to use the key.If  incorrect, SBT may fall back to using a password.

--Enable verbose SSH logging. Add the following line to your `~/.ssh/config` file

```
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

will increase the SSH logging level, and you should see detailed information about the SSH connection  ( usually `/var/log/auth.log or /var/log/secure`)

--Ensure that the key you want to use is added to the agent. You can use the ssh-add command to add your key to the agent

```
ssh-add /PATH/TO/.ssh/oat_rsa
```

--Verify `SBT configuration` :Ensure  correct `SSH key` file and account information are provided. Also, confirm that the `REPO_HOST_MACHINE` is the correct `hostname or IP` address of the `repository` host.

The documentation mentioning `realm and host keys` is related to `HTTP` Basic Authentication, not SSH authentication.

--Changing the `SSH` key filename to a non-existent file like `.ssh/oat_rsaXXX` should throw an error because SBT won't be able to locate the key file. So not sure why things aren't so in your case.

--To trace the SSH calls between SBT and the server, you can enable SSH debug output by setting the SSH_DEBUG environment variable before running SBT.

-> To enable debug logging for `Ivy` in SBT, you can add the following line to your `build.sbt` file:

```
ivyLoggingLevel := UpdateLogging.Full
```

-> For `Coursier`

```
dependencyResolution := dependencyResolution.value.withLogging(logger => new ConsoleLogger(logger, sys.env.get("SBT_COURSIER_LOG_LEVEL").fold(CoursierLogger.Level.Warn)(CoursierLogger.Level.withName)))
```

If `SBT` can't connect via `SSH`, it won't automatically fall back to a password prompt. It should instead fail with an error indicating the SSH connection failure. In your case, it seems like `SBT` is attempting `SSH` connections but is unable to authenticate with your `SSH key.`

From the above few pointer checks :

--Verify that the SSH key file is not password-protected, or if it is, ensure that you're providing the correct passphrase.

---Check the SSH server logs on the repository host machine to see if there are any relevant error messages or authentication failures.

--Test the SSH connection *manually* using the ssh command from the same machine where you're running SBT, to ensure that SSH authentication is working correctly.

**Updates**

It seems like you’ve already tried setting the `LogLevel` in your `~/.ssh/config` file and it didn’t help. You also mentioned that you couldn’t find verbose SSH logging in any log files and that you don’t think SBT is using the usual SSH infrastructure.

Try running SBT with the -debug flag
:

```
sbt -debug
```

This will print detailed debug information to the console when you run SBT. It might help you figure out why SBT is not using the specified SSH key.

You also mentioned that setting `ivyLoggingLevel` showed a little extra info about fetching but nothing about publishing. You could try setting the `logLevel` setting in your `build.sbt` file to `Level.Debug`

```
logLevel := Level.Debug
```

Comment: Thanks, @user1874594, but still not solved.  
-- SSH key file already had 600 permissions.
-- ssh works manually: `ssh USER@MACHINE -i ~/.shh/oat_rsa` 
-- Set LogLevel in .ssh/config.  I can't find verbose ssh logging in any log files; it comes to STDERR if I run it manually.  Also checked the console app. Given the stack trace from SBT, I don't think it's using the usual SSH infrastructure.
-- SBT config: another library that worked on May 2 does the same thing.
-- Setting `export SSH_DEBUG=''` didn't change behaviour that I can see.  Googling for SSH_DEBUG didn't turn anything up.

Comment: -- Setting ivyLoggingLevel seemed to show a little extra info about fetching (the first time); nothing about publishing

-- Adding the suggested `dependencyResolution` line for Courier gives an error:  /Users/bwbecker/oat/src/oat-degreeAudit3/build.sbt:67: error: value withLogging is not a member of sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.  Google search for "sbt dependencyResolution withLogging" turns up nothing.

Comment: I've asked for server logs but don't have them yet.

Still a mystery why it doesn't error when I give it a bogus key file.  But the `show publishTo` command yields expected info.

Comment: see  updates. Easier to stick em to the main answer

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up.  The combination of -debug and logLevel produced a LOT more info, but only one line related to the actual problem:  [debug] :: SSH :: connecting to ubuntu2204-102.cs.uwaterloo.ca...  This is the point where it shows the password dialog box (with the username and machine name correctly filled in).  Still no explanation for why it ignores the ssh key.  As stated in my post, the show publishTo indicates it's reading the config.  SBT just seems to be ignoring part of it.

Comment: I've filed a bug report with SBT.  Renaming the .ssh directory yields exactly the same behaviour, so it's not an SSH problem; it's an SBT problem.  It reads the config correctly (confirmed by `show publishTo`), it's just ignoring part of it.  Awarding the bounty to @user1874594; thanks for the effort and the useful information even though my issue is not yet solved.

Comment: good luk    .  .. if I dig up something more will post it here to try out